# jQuery Offset wrong on refresh of page

Tags: jquery, positioning

I'm using jQuery offset function to place an absolutely positioned DIV over an anchor element.

```
$("#marker1").offset({ top: $("#<%= hypHowItWorks.ClientID %>").offset().top, left: $("#<%= hypHowItWorks.ClientID %>").offset().left });
$("#marker1").width( $("#<%= hypHowItWorks.ClientID %>").outerWidth() );
```

When the page loads up this works fine, however, if I reload the page by hitting F5, it displays the DIV slightly offset from where it shoud be. If I then go page back-forward in the browser its in the right place again!!

This is an issue with latest Chrome and Firefox, but not with IE9.

Any ideas?

Chris.

Comment: Are your script inside of the `$(document).ready` callback?

Comment: It's hard to [reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/5gkSr/) that error, but you can open the page in Firefox and press `Ctrl+Shift+i`, hover and click with the mouse over that _#marker_ and you will see, which style attribute has changed and why it became slightly offseted.

Comment: Hi Stano, nothing about the anchor has changed on refresh

Comment: Seems if I zoom in and out ( CTRL-CURSORUP/DOWN) the DIV moves relative to the underlying anchor as well. I'm clearly not doing this right but I dont know how I'm doing it wrong!

Answer (score 13):

Try it in the `$(window).load` event instead of `$(document).ready`.

I had the same problem and could fix it with that trick!